# Error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'", but cors allows everything

Tags: asp.net, angular, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use a get request on my web page (made in angular) that refers to my own api (created with APS.NET core). I get the following error in my chrome debugging tool:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

This is odd, because i put the following in my startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
        );
```

So everything should be allowed? 
This is the code i use for the GET request:

```
ngOnInit(){
  debugger;
  this._svc.getAllMagicItems().subscribe(result =>{
    debugger;
    console.log(result);
    debugger;
    this.items = Array.of(result);
    debugger;
  })
}
```

*getAllMagicItems()* executes this code:

```
getAllMagicItems(): Observable<IImageRootObject> {
    return this._http.get<IImageRootObject>("http://localhost:63514/api/v1/MagicItem");
}
```

How do I solve this CORSE problem?

Comment: You need to inspect the response headers on the network request, and the preflight request is 204. Post them up.

Comment: Provisional headers are shown
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36

Comment: Is this one correct?

Comment: Nope. Do you see an options request? Any mention of Access-Control headers?

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:63514/api/v1/MagicItem
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:63514
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

oddly enough, i did find this one, which has the data i need in with an "ok" header (code 200). So it did send the data, but it wouldn't accept it?

Comment: take a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144933/vs2017-web-application-cors-access-control-allow-origin/51157235#51157235), I get the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144933/vs2017-web-application-cors-access-control-allow-origin/51157235#51157235) Giancarlo Benitez provided shows, my problem lied in calling *services.AddCors()* and *services.AddMVC()*. My problem was that I called *AddMVC()* first, but the CORS-headers need to be allowed before MVC initializes. So load them in this order:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddCors();       /* <----- Added this line before de MVC */
  services.AddMvc();
}
```